# Disable Network Location Wizard in Windows on Azure

Tags: windows, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a problem with WPF automation - when I'm running automation on a virtual machine, I see on the video recorder this window. The window changes focus and automation cant work.

Maybe I can disable that window by power-shell script or is there some other solution?

[image]

Comment: @Paolo not helped.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a new registry key. In Powershell:

```
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\NewNetworkWindowOff\"
```